# PHP: What are language constructs and why do we need them?

Tags: php, language-construct

I keep coming across statements like:

> `echo` is a language construct but
> print is a function and hence has a
> return value

and

> `die` is a language construct

My question is what are these language constructs and more importantly why do we need them?

Comment: `print` is also a language construct. It has a value, but it’s not actually a return value. The value makes it possible to combine `print` with other instructions in the same statement. You can recognise `print` as a language construct in that it doesn’t require parentheses.

Answer (score 29):

Language constructs are hard coded into the PHP language. They do not play by normal rules.

For example, whenever you try to access a variable that doesn't exist, you'd get an error. To test whether a variable exists before you access it, you need to consult `isset` or `empty`:

```
if (isset($foo))
```

If `isset` was a normal function, you'd get a warning there as well, since you're accessing `$foo` to pass it into the function `isset`. Since `isset` is a language construct though, this works without throwing a warning. That's why the documentation makes a clear distinction between normal functions and language constructs.

Answer (score 12):

Language constructs are what makes up the language: things like "if" "for" "while" "function" and so on.

The mentions in the PHP manual of things like "echo", "die" or "return" are there to make it clear that these are NOT functions and that they do not always behave like functions.

You could call "echo" as "echo()" so it may confuse beginners. That's why they put the clear disinction in the manual. To make it absolutely clear to everyone.

Other examples for language constructs that could be mistaken for functions are "array()", "list()" and "each()".

Comment: Unfortunately, the syntax description of language constructs in the PHP manual is also confusing. Just take a look at the one for `echo`: it says `void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )` but `echo ($arg1, $arg2);` is invalid.

Answer (score 6):

To understand the answer for this question you must understand how parsers work. A language is defined by syntax and the syntax is defined through keywords.

The language constructs are pieces of code that make the base of PHP language. The parser deals with them directly instead of functions.

Answer (score 4):

Not all of a language can be functions.  There must be some base, somewhere, on which you implement those **first** functions.  The elements of this base are the language constructs (alternately, *built-ins*).  They don't always behave like "normal" functions do.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, a **language construct** is any instruction which is built into the language itself, while a **function** is an additional block of code.

In some cases, a language may choose to build in a particular feature or to rely on a separate function.

For example, PHP has the `print` language construct, which outputs a string. Many other languages, such as **C** don’t build it in, but implement it as a function. There might be technical reasons for taking one or other approach, but sometimes it is more philosophical — whether the feature should be regarded as core or additional.

For practical purposes, while functions follow a rigid set of logistic rules, language constructs don’t. Sometimes, that’s because they may be doing something which would otherwise traumatise a regular function. For example, `isset(…)`, by its very purpose, may be referencing something which doesn’t exist. Functions don’t handle that at all well.

Here are some of the characteristics of language constructs:

- Many don’t require parentheses; some do *sometimes*.
- Language Constructs are processed in a different stage; functions are processed later
- Some Language Constructs, such as `isset` do things which would be impossible as functions; some others, such as `Array(…)` could have gone either way.
- Some Language Constructs certainly don’t look like functions. For example, the `Array(…)` construct can be written as `[…]`.
- As the documentation keeps reminding us, language constructs cannot be referenced as variable variables. So `$a='print_r'; $a(…);` is OK, but `$a='print'; $a(…);` isn’t.

Answer (score 2):

Some things are just not possible using normal functions, consider this snippet:

`list($el1, $el2) = array('el1', 'el2');`

What it does is it takes the elements from a non-associative array and assigns the values to the variables defined in the `list()` construct.

Simply cannot be done with functions :)

A more subtle example is `isset`and `empty`. Though they look like functions, they one thing that's not possible with functions alone – they do not generate "variable is undefined" or "undefined index" notices.

Comment: You can re-implement `empty` with `isset`: `function empty(&$var) { return !isset($var) || !$var; }`

Answer (score 2):

language constructs can be formed in more than one way and has a return-value

`print("asdf");` is as possible as `print "asdf";` and will return 1.

`echo("asdf");` is equal to `echo "asdf;"` but has no return-value.

`die("asdf");` is equal to `exit("asdf");` and hasn't a return-value too.

Comment: Actually, `die` and `exit` do have a value, but you never get to see it. This is why you can use them in a statement such as `doSomething() or die('oops');`. The `or` operator needs to be between values.