# What is the difference between echo with braces and without braces, and why do both methods exist?

Tags: php, syntax, echo, parentheses, language-construct

I think most of us that program in php learned to `echo "string";`. While common, I am wondering why we use this so different then any other function.

So why do we do:

`echo "Some String";`

Instead of

`echo("Some String");`

And why do both exist and behave differently? Is there any reference to why this choice was made?

People refer to the php docs stating that echo is a language construct and therefor is used differently. But in that case, since we can both use it as a construct aswell as functional: which is the preferred method? And why was it implemented both ways while it should only be a language construct?

The same as above pretty much counts for `require`, `require_once`, `include` and `include_once`. I can't find anything on the web explaining -why- these constructs were also implemented functional (and in the case of echo(), in a flawed way).

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between a language construct and a "built-in" function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180184/2943403)

Comment: Also related: [PHP: What are language constructs and why do we need them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3254327/2943403)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/echo):

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
> are not required to use parentheses with it.

> if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters
> must not be enclosed within parentheses.

**Example:**

```
<?php
echo(1);        // < works fine
echo(1, 2, 3);  // < Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 3
echo 1;         // < works fine
echo 1, 2, 3;   // < works fine
echo (1), (2), (3);   // < works fine
```

Regarding your question "why do both methods exist?", using braces is not actually a "method". Those braces do not belong to `echo`, but to its argument. In PHP, almost any expression can be taken in braces. For example, `($a = 1);` and `$a = (1)` are valid statements. So it's just an *extra pair of braces*. As well as in `trim(($str));`, where first pair of braces belongs to the function and the second pair - to its argument. So now you can tell that using `echo` with braces is as logical as using `trim()` with 2 pairs of braces.

Everything said above is also applied to `include`, `require`, `require_once` and `include_once`, as well as other language constructs, but with some exceptions. For example, `isset`, although being a language construct, for some reason requires a pair of braces.

Note that, as it's mentioned on the manual page for [include](http://php.net/include), these language constructs have a return value. And because expressions like `include 'fileA.php' == 'OK'` are not obvious (according to [*operator precedence*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)), when checking for the return value, you should use parentheses, either wrapping the entire expression: `(include 'fileA.php') == 'OK'` or the argument only: `include('fileA.php') == 'OK'`.

Comment: Best answer so far, thanks @Corrupt. I'm still wondering why the developers made the "language construct" usable in a functional way though. Especially since it behaves differently. Is this just a "fluke" in the php dev history? Or was there a good reason behind it?

Comment: @Damien Overeem , backward capability issues, maybe.

Comment: Seems this is not considered a "real question". Which is odd if you ask me, but whatever. I would have loved to find out the reasoning behind this kinda strang behavior... I'll accept your answer though, since it did point out the silly difference between the 2 methods.

Comment: @Damien Overeem I've updated answer with test of _variable function_  call.

Comment: Nice catch. Makes the existance of `echo();` even more awkward. It works, but has total unexpected behavior...

Comment: @Damien Overeem updated to fit requirements of **Edit 2**.

Comment: Rather interesting. I didn't even know you could `return` in an include file. Rather nasty thing to actually use though, but interesting to know.

Comment: @Damien Overeem Yes, I'm not using it too, but someone somewhere may do it in some incomprehensible way. It is not `evUl` until it is not in curved hands.

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP docs

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want
>   to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be
>   enclosed within parentheses

It's not a funcion, hence no parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Because is a statement(language construct) it is not a function. Hence to differentiate a function and statement it is used like this.