# PHP: Why ERROR constant produces error?

Tags: php, constants

I am using following code:

```
define ('EMPTY', 'test');
echo EMPTY;
```

But I am unable to get output. I am getting following Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '('
```

Comment: Maria, using an IDE, like PHPStorm or Netbeans, should give you real-time information on whether you are using a reserved word as well as many other enhancements designed to save you time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Empty](http://docs.php.net/empty) is a reserved word.

```
<?php

define ('EMPTY2', 'test');
echo EMPTY2;
```

Works as intended.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
How can we know that if some word is reserved or not? I checked the link you provided above. On that link it does not say that EMPTY is reserved word.

Comment: The documentation is located at http://php.net (here's the link: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php)

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. I checked link but  even in that link I did not find "EMPTY" as reserved. It has "empty()" as reserved but not "EMPTY". I did not find that anywhere.

Comment: All those are case insensitive.

Comment: Yes I understand that but they have parentheses " empty() " not just "empty" or "EMPTY"

Comment: Ther're called "language constructs". Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254327/php-what-are-language-constructs-and-why-do-we-need-them

Comment: @Maria: ...which is why PHP is complaining. You used the reserved word `empty` and then it's expecting `()`.