# Why can I omit only echo's parentheses from php?

Tags: php, echo

I was learning php, but I am wondering why I can only omit the parentheses for 'echo' as other functions should not omit the parentheses.

```
echo "test <br>";
echo("test <br>");
$a = sin 4; //ERROR
$a = sin(4);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), which comments that `echo` isn't actually a PHP function:

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.

Comment: Would be great to know what was the design decision behind making it a language construct. Python's `print` was also language construct/statement before Python 3, but function after that.

Also found an question that also wanted to know the why, but it seems that there's no good answer there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254327/php-what-are-language-constructs-and-why-do-we-need-them

Comment: @Hendrik Off the top of my head, the creators of PHP perhaps wanted their `echo` to bear some resemblance to the `echo` found in Linux, which also is a language construct.

Answer (score 0):

**echo — Output one or more strings**

```php
  
  echo ('foor','bar','ba'); //will not work
  echo ('foo'); //will work
```

**but**

```php
 echo 'foo','bar','ba'; //will work
```

can also be used for brackets type casting in PHP, for example

```php
 $string="63";
 $number=(int)$string;
 
 echo  gettype($number)."\n"; //integer
 echo  gettype($string)."\n"; //string
```

> For this reason, the parentheses might surprise you because parentheses are not only used in functions, for example, I gave a typecast example.In addition, parentheses are used in mathematical operations, dynamic scripting languages ​​can also be such things. Not like static scripting languages