# PHP Or operator with function

Tags: php

I've seen this code: `defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;`

My understanding is that the `OR` operator returns true if one of them is true. But in this case, `exit` is a function rather than an assessment to be tested. So is this means that if `defined( 'ABSPATH' )` is false, then execute the `exit`? Why it will execute if it's false?

Comment: This is what's known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: FYI `exit` is a language construct, not a function. There are [subtle differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3254327/283366)

Comment: @Phil Noted with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a total guess on my part but my understanding is that this is taking advantage of PHP's lazy evaluation processing. When it encounters values separated by `||` it will stop evaluating after the first one is true.

For example, the *final false* will not be checked since the preceding expression is true.

`if (false || true || false) { ... }`

So, `defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;` will first evaluate `defined( 'ABSPATH' )` and if it is true, it will skip the 2nd expression and the program will continue. Only if it is false will it execute the final expression `exit` and terminate the program.

Comment: In addition to this answer: this specific `defined` condition is usually located in the top of the source file and was used in pre-OOP epoch to prevent execution of the source file by calling it by it's path in the browser (the constant should be defined in the separate file that acts as an endpoint of the website).